# Django Social Auth store username from Facebook in Custom User Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-socialauth

I've just integrated Django-Social-Auth (DSA) v0.7.23 using django 1.5 with a custom User model and auth/login is working fine except for the username field which is not being stored in my custom User model.

Stepping through the DSA code it appears to explicitly remove the username which was passed back by facebook. Here is the function in question that pops the username off:

```
@classmethod
def username_field(cls, values):
    user_model = cls.user_model()
    if hasattr(user_model, 'USERNAME_FIELD'):
        # Django 1.5 custom user model, 'username' is just for internal
        # use, doesn't imply that the model should have an username field
        values[user_model.USERNAME_FIELD] = values.pop('username') # Username removed
    return values
```

How can I go about getting the username that was passed back from facebook and not having it be explicitly removed by DSA?

I believe a work around would be to create a custom pipeline that generates a username. However I was wondering if anyone else encountered this scenario before and leveraged anything that already exists within DSA (i.e. a particular settings.py configuration)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original username is available in the `details` attribute passed to pipeline functions, take this for example:

```
def generated_username(user, details, *args, **kwargs):
    username = details['username']
    user.your_field = username
    user.save()
```

It's worth noting that the username is popped from values if you have a `USERNAME_FIELD` defined in your custom model.

Comment: Thanks omab for the sample pipeline which is the route I had taken. I was more confused on why the username should be popped if a USERNAME_FIELD is defined. My custom user table wants the username returned from facebook so it can be stored in the username field.